# Append file name using CSV

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to rename files that match values in column one of a csv adding the value in column 3 to the beginning of the file name leaving the rest of the file name intact. Here is what I have so far. I cant seem to figure out the Rename-Item.

```
# Common Paths
$PathRoot = "C:\Temp\somefiles" #Where the files are to rename

# Get csv file
$ClientAccounts = Import-CSV -path "\\server\some\path\to\csv\file.csv"

# Get each file and rename it
ForEach($row in $ClientAccounts) 
{
    $CurrentClientTaxId = $row[-1].TaxId
    $CurrentClientName = $row[-1].ClientName 

    #loop through files

    $FileExists = Test-Path -Path "$PathTotal\*$CurrentClientLB_Number*" #See if there is a file.

    If ($FileExists -eq $true) #The file does exist.
    {

        #ReName File
        Rename-Item -Path $PathRoot -NewName {$CurrentClientName + " " + $_.name}
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you using `$row[-1].TaxId` instead of `$row.TaxId`?  What is `$row[-1]` supposed to mean?  And shouldn't you be pulling `$CurrentClientLB_Number` from the CSV file somewhere?

Comment: For your Rename-Item command, curly braces mean a script block, not an expression.  You want either `Rename-Item -Path $PathRoot -NewName $($CurrentClientName + " " + $_.name)` or `Rename-Item -Path $PathRoot -NewName ($CurrentClientName + " " + $_.name)`.  And I think your logic is wrong, too.  `$PathRoot` there makes no sense.

Comment: Thank you Bacon Bits! - There were several typos and mistakes. I have cleaned up everything but not sure how to reference each file as it loops through. `Rename-Item ????? -NewName ($CurrentClientName + " " + $_.Name)`. You're very correct in that `$PathRoot` was incorrect.

Comment: Please show us some of the stuff in the `\\server\some\path\to\csv\file.csv` file. Now it is totally unclear where `$CurrentClientLB_Number` comes from and if it perhaps contains invalid filename characters. Also.. what is `$PathTotal` ??

Comment: @BaconBits I agree at first I also thought the curly braces are wrong, but if you look up [Rename-Item](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/rename-item?view=powershell-6) and scroll down to example 4, the article explains that it is actualy legit code. I tested it with PowerShell 5.1 and it works.

Comment: @Theo Yes, the documentation does that in several places.  Nevertheless, `{ ... }` indicates a ScriptBlock literal, not a string literal.  Casting ScriptBlock to a string can often behave inconsistently in certain scenarios, and you'll notice that the `-NewName` parameter of `Rename-Item` is always String.  `$()` and `()` are always safer, IMX.

Answer (score 0):

Lets suppose your CSV file looks similar to this:

```
"LB_Number","TaxId","ClientName"
"987654","12345","Microsoft"
"321456","91234","Apple"
"741852","81234","HP"
```

<sup>Column 1 has the portion of the existing file name to match

Column 3 has the client name you want to prepend to the file name</sup>

Then your function could be something like this:

```
# Common Paths
$PathRoot = "C:\Temp\somefiles" # Where the files are to rename

# Get csv file
$ClientAccounts = Import-CSV -path "\\server\some\path\to\csv\file.csv"

# Loop through all clients in the CSV
foreach($client in $ClientAccounts) {
    $CurrentClientLB_Number = $client.LB_Number
    $CurrentClientTaxId     = $client.TaxId       # unused...??
    $CurrentClientName      = $client.ClientName 

    # get the file(s) using wildcards (there can be more than one)
    # and rename them
    Get-ChildItem -Path "$PathRoot\*$CurrentClientLB_Number*" -File | ForEach-Object {
        $_ | Rename-Item -NewName ($CurrentClientName + " " + $_.Name) 
    }

    # Curly braces work also, although this is not very common practice:
    # Get-ChildItem -Path "$PathRoot\*$CurrentClientLB_Number*" -File | 
    #     Rename-Item -NewName { ($CurrentClientName + " " + $_.Name) }
}
```

I use the `-File` parameter with `Get-ChildItem` so the function will only return files; not directories. If you are using PowerShell version 2.0, you need to replace that with `| Where-Object { !$_.PSIsContainer }`.

Comment: Theo you got it exact (even with my typos and mess) $client.LB_Number came from another project I was working and should not have been there at all. Thank you all!

Comment: @TomRanch Good to hear! If you feel my answer has helped you, please consider accepting it. An accepted answer is easier to find for people facing the same problem.